# Combine columns of a dataframe by dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame:

```
d = [{
"A" : 1,
"B.C" : 2,
"B.D" : 3,
"E[0].F" : 4,
"E[0].G[0]" : 5,
},
{
"A" : 6,
"B.C" : 7,
"B.D" : 8,
"E[0].F" : 9,
"E[0].G[0]" : 10,
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

```
    A   B.C B.D E[0].F  E[0].G[0]

    1   2   3   4   5
    6   7   8   9   10
```

The columns represents a structure of a dictionary. Each left letter in this example is the main dictionary keys. I wish to keep the main dictionary's keys only while each column will be mapped as the structure is in its' name.

A column may contain the following name: E[0].G[1].H.I[3]. A list is represented by the brackets ([]) and a dictionary key is represented by a dot (.). Each list / dictionary has to be represented separately inside the big dictionary.

In our example this is the result I aim for:

```
    A   B                     E

    1   {'C': 2, 'D': 3}    [{'F': 4, 'G': [5]}]
    6   {'C': 7, 'D': 8}    [{'F': 9, 'G': [10]}]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

I tried to use `pd.to_dict` and `pd.from_dict` but I couldn't find the right way to use those functions.

Comment: Is the original data frame what you were given? Wondering if we're looking at an XY problem.

Comment: https://github.com/dairiki/unflatten

Answer (score 0):

A more clearer and comprehensible way is to reorganize your initial list of dicts to obtain the needed structure:

```
lst_grouped = []
for d in lst:
    d_ = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if '.' in k:
            p_key, sub_key = k.split('.')
            if sub_key.endswith('[0]'):
                sub_key = sub_key.rstrip('[0]')
                v = [v]
            if p_key.endswith('[0]'):
                d_.setdefault(p_key.rstrip('[0]'), [{}])[-1][sub_key] = v
            else:
                d_.setdefault(p_key, {})[sub_key] = v
        else:
            d_[k] = v
    lst_grouped.append(d_)

print(pd.DataFrame(lst_grouped))
```

---

```
   A                 B                      E
0  1  {'C': 2, 'D': 3}   [{'F': 4, 'G': [5]}]
1  6  {'C': 7, 'D': 8}  [{'F': 9, 'G': [10]}]
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning  that the nested lists may get other values than 0 inside the brackets ([1] or [2] for example). Do you have any idea how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that with recursive function. The available columns must be repeated depending on how deep the nested dict / array is. Try this :

```
# 'A[1]' => 1; 'A' => ''
def getIndex(s): 
  res = s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]
  return res if res == '' else int(res) 

# 'A[1]' => 'A'; 'A' => 'A'
def getVariable(s):
  return s[:s.find("[")] if '[' in s else s

def positioning(obj, column, value, level):
  index = getIndex(column[level])
  variable = getVariable(column[level])
  if index == '':
    if variable not in list(obj.keys()):
      obj[variable] = {}
    if level == len(column) - 1:
      obj[variable] = value
    if not level == len(column) - 1:
      positioning(obj[variable], column, value, level + 1)
  else:
    if variable not in list(obj.keys()):
      obj[variable] = []
    while len(obj[variable]) - 1 < index:
      obj[variable].append({})
    if level == len(column) - 1:
      obj[variable][index] = value
    if not level == len(column) - 1:
      positioning(obj[variable][index], column, value, level + 1)

columns = []
data = []
dataNew = []
for i in range(len(df)):
  data.append({})
  for j in df.columns:
    columnList = j.split('.')
    if getVariable(columnList[0]) not in columns:
      columns.append(getVariable(columnList[0]))
    positioning(data[i], columnList, df.at[i,j], 0)
for i in range(len(df)):
  dataNew.append([])
  for j in columns:
    dataNew[i].append(str(data[i][j]))
newDf = pd.DataFrame(dataNew, columns=columns)
newDf
```

---

Input:

|  | A | B.C | B.D | E[0].F | E[0].G[0] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |

Output:

|  | A | B | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | {'C': 2, 'D': 3} | [{'F': 4, 'G': [5]}] |
| 1 | 6 | {'C': 7, 'D': 8} | [{'F': 9, 'G': [10]}] |

---

Input:

|  | A | B.C | B.D | E[0].F | E[0].G[0] | E[0].G[1].H.I[3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 11 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 12 |

Ouput:

|  | A | B | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | {'C': 2, 'D': 3} | [{'F': 4, 'G': [5, {'H': {'I': [{}, {}, {}, 11]}}]}] |
| 1 | 6 | {'C': 7, 'D': 8} | [{'F': 9, 'G': [10, {'H': {'I': [{}, {}, {}, 12]}}]}] |

Answer (score 0):

Just found this package -- [`unflatten`](https://github.com/dairiki/unflatten). Seems to do exactly what you want.

```py
import pandas as pd
from unflatten import unflatten


list_of_dicts = [
    {
        "A": 1,
        "B.C": 2,
        "B.D": 3,
        "E[0].F": 4,
        "E[0].G[0]": 5,
    },
    {
        "A": 6,
        "B.C": 7,
        "B.D": 8,
        "E[0].F": 9,
        "E[0].G[0]": 10,
    },
]

# standard for-loop
# for idx, d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
#     unflat = unflatten(d)
#     list_of_dicts[idx] = unflat

# more functional approach
list_of_dicts = [*map(unflatten, list_of_dicts)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
print(df)
```

```
   A                 B                      E
0  1  {'C': 2, 'D': 3}   [{'F': 4, 'G': [5]}]
1  6  {'C': 7, 'D': 8}  [{'F': 9, 'G': [10]}]
```